# Rearrange arrays so I don't have to flip it for imshow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I made a mistake while saving my data for my Machine Learning Project.

It is my first big project, so I made some mistakes along the way and now have the following problem:

All my data (I saved each instance of training input and output as .npys) is flipped, because when I built the preprocessing program I thought of arrays in cartesian coordinates (shape = (max_x,max_y)) and not by (rows, columns).

This lead to the following problem:

All my inputs and outputs have to be transposed and for imshow and i have to specify the origin to "lower".

To summarize: 
I need a way to rearange my arrays in the following fashion (as I do in pyplot.imshow()):

```
plt.imshow(array.T, origin = "lower")
```

So how do I rearrange all my data, so I can just call:

```
plt.imshow(array)
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`np.rot90()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)

axs[0].imshow(arr.T, origin='lower')
axs[1].imshow(np.rot90(arr))
```

[image]